# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') React Native Reanimated Carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to use `React native reanimated carousel` in an expo project knowing that I have already used it on a previous one and it worked fine. So I copied and pasted the same code but for an unknown reason I get the following error:

*`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`*

So I used the bare code [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated-carousel#Usage) from the documentation and found out I still get the same issue.
Here are the version the packages I'm using :

```
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
"react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.1.5",
```

Example.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';

function Index() {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Carousel
                loop
                width={width}
                height={width / 2}
                autoPlay={true}
                data={[...new Array(6).keys()]}
                scrollAnimationDuration={1000}
                onSnapToItem={(index) => console.log('current index:', index)}
                renderItem={({ index }) => (
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30 }}>
                            {index}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: I got same problem, but I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurred because of the absence of the reanimated plugin in the `babel.config.js`. Based off of the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/) here's what needs to be done.

Add Reanimated's Babel plugin to your `babel.config.js`

```
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me;

**babel.config.js**

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
```

and "expo start -c"

Comment: This worked for my expo RN project.
I guess every time `babel.config.js` is updated, it's important to restart the project with the flag `-c`.

Comment: Restarting the project with the flag `-c` was critical for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your `renderItem` function. You generate list of integers as data and try to pass the integer as a child to:

```js
<Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30 }}>
   {index}
</Text>
```

replace it with

```js
<Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30 }}>
   {`${index}`}
</Text>
```